# python MySQLdb won't INSERT

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using [python-mysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python), attacked below is the code snippet I'm using to insert into a database table. For some reasons, the code is not populating any rows in the database. There are no exceptions raised and the *SELECT* queries work fine. On copying the code inside execute and running in phpmyadmin, the database is populated fine.

```
    import MySQLdb as mdb
try:
    con = mdb.connect(host='localhost', user='', passwd='', db='indoor')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO locationdata VALUES('1','1','1','1','1','1')")
    numrows = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM locationdata")
    print str(numrows) + " : total Rows"
    print cur.fetchone()
    if con.open:
      print "Hello DB"
except mdb.Error, e:
    Print "Error " + e. args [0]
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: What if you add `con.commit()` after the `execute()` with `INSERT` command?

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you explain what does the .commit method do? The examples provided don't seem to refer it much. http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/query.html